# Ruby: Mark an object for garbage collection

Tags: ruby, oop, garbage-collection

I was wondering if there is a similar .finalize() method for Ruby objects, that marks them ready for garbage collection. If I would create 20,000 objects and each instance has a counter, I would like the object to be marked for garbage collection when reaches zero. I know this is pretty much a Java approach, but I have not sufficient experience with Ruby under-the-hood to understand how this could be done better.

Thank you for your answers, comments and feedback!

Comment: finalize doesn't mark objects for garbage collection, it's a method that runs (although there's no guarantee) just before the GC deletes the object

Comment: Thats good to know, thank you for pointing that out. Is there a specific method that explicitly destroy the object or at least put this at motion? I like magic, but I also like to understand the tricks exposed.

Comment: _why wrote an awesome article on GC in Ruby called "The Fully Upturned Bin" which luckily got saved when he decided to disappear from the Internet: http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/theFullyUpturnedBin.html

Comment: You just need to remove all references to the object e. g. if you have one reference x you just set it to null or you have a local variable thet gets out of scope. If there are no references an object it's available to the GC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't mark an object ready for GC but you can force GC at any time:

```
GC.start
```

If the item can be freed, it will be freed.

Comment: No longer true since MRI 1.9.3 introduced lazy sweep GC

Comment: This part is still true though: "you can't mark an object ready for GC". Ruby uses the opposite approach - objects that can be reached are marked as "do not remove". Everything else is freed after the mark phase completes. This has not changed, it just doesn't happen immediately when you call `GC.start`